# Using each for object with an array of objects

Tags: ruby, each

I have an object `@cars = Cars` that has an array `car_array` of objects `Car` that have instance variables `@id` and `@mileage`, so, writing it as pseudo array it's:

```
Cars = [
    Car1 = [1, 12000],
    Car2 = [2, 33000]
]
```

Is there a way to write an `each` method to iterate over the cars, in this way:

```
@cars.each do |id, mileage|
    ...
end
```

?

I've tried to do a custom `each` method in `Cars`:

```
def each(&block)
    @car_array.each(&block)
end
```

but that would only return each `Car` object into the enumerator. How would I then convert each `Car` object to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby we do chain methods to accomplish different complicated transforms:

```
@cars.map do |car|
  [car.id, car.mileage]
end.each do |id, mileage|
    ...
end
```